# Apps Script: Copy HTML text to doc and keep formatting

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've built a simple Google Docs add-on that allows me to search for info from an API, get some results and then click on the results and it gets pasted into the doc. My code for inserting the text:

```
function insertVerseToDoc(verseText){
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  .getCursor()
  .insertText(verseText)
  .setFontFamily("Proxima Nova");
}
```

The code works, but I noticed that it inserts the text as HTML, so I end up with this:

```
 <b> Lorem ipsum</b> <br>sample text.
```

Is there a way to make sure the inserted text keeps the HTML formatting instead of it inserting it as raw text?

Comment: I cannot understand about the detail of `a way to make sure the inserted text keeps the HTML formatting instead of it inserting it as raw text`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: So the results (`verseText`) are coming as HTML. Do you have a way to return only the inner text to Apps Script?